# Is it possible to automate Internet Explorer on an EC2 instance?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, amazon-ec2

I would like to scrape some data from a website that only seems to show up in internet explorer, I have booted up a Windows Server 2019 EC2 instance and was hoping to install Python and Selenium along with a webdriver for internet explorer but I can't seem to download any software when connected to my Windows Server via RDP from my linux machine, are there any other methods you could suggest for automating Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to the instance (RDP) ------> go to server manager -----> head to local server -------> Find IE Enhanced Security Configuration and click on On ------> rn off IE ESC for Administrators and/or for Users and click OK.

You are good to download any content now.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me with another issue where a site would not load fully on IE :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to download with internet explorer, go to the cog symbol > internet options > security

Then select each of the zones and *untick* the box marked 'Enable protected mode'

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.